# JCTVC-G763 CE1: Table-based bit estimation for CABAC

Tags: hevc

JCTVC-G763 says: "This new table was derived using the table defining the LPS ranges for each state. When deriving this new table it was assumed that the range register in the CABAC engine takes value R with a probability proportional to 1/R". How to understand it?
How to produce array `m_entropyBits`?

```
const Int ContextModel::m_entropyBits[ ContextModel::m_totalStates ] =
{

#ifdef FAST_BIT_EST
  // Corrected table, most notably for last state

  0x07b23, 0x085f9, 0x074a0, 0x08cbc, 0x06ee4, 0x09354, 0x067f4, 0x09c1b, 0x060b0, 0x0a62a, 0x05a9c, 0x0af5b, 0x0548d, 0x0b955, 0x04f56, 0x0c2a9,
  0x04a87, 0x0cbf7, 0x045d6, 0x0d5c3, 0x04144, 0x0e01b, 0x03d88, 0x0e937, 0x039e0, 0x0f2cd, 0x03663, 0x0fc9e, 0x03347, 0x10600, 0x03050, 0x10f95,
  0x02d4d, 0x11a02, 0x02ad3, 0x12333, 0x0286e, 0x12cad, 0x02604, 0x136df, 0x02425, 0x13f48, 0x021f4, 0x149c4, 0x0203e, 0x1527b, 0x01e4d, 0x15d00,
  0x01c99, 0x166de, 0x01b18, 0x17017, 0x019a5, 0x17988, 0x01841, 0x18327, 0x016df, 0x18d50, 0x015d9, 0x19547, 0x0147c, 0x1a083, 0x0138e, 0x1a8a3,
  0x01251, 0x1b418, 0x01166, 0x1bd27, 0x01068, 0x1c77b, 0x00f7f, 0x1d18e, 0x00eda, 0x1d91a, 0x00e19, 0x1e254, 0x00d4f, 0x1ec9a, 0x00c90, 0x1f6e0,
  0x00c01, 0x1fef8, 0x00b5f, 0x208b1, 0x00ab6, 0x21362, 0x00a15, 0x21e46, 0x00988, 0x2285d, 0x00934, 0x22ea8, 0x008a8, 0x239b2, 0x0081d, 0x24577,
  0x007c9, 0x24ce6, 0x00763, 0x25663, 0x00710, 0x25e8f, 0x006a0, 0x26a26, 0x00672, 0x26f23, 0x005e8, 0x27ef8, 0x005ba, 0x284b5, 0x0055e, 0x29057,
  0x0050c, 0x29bab, 0x004c1, 0x2a674, 0x004a7, 0x2aa5e, 0x0046f, 0x2b32f, 0x0041f, 0x2c0ad, 0x003e7, 0x2ca8d, 0x003ba, 0x2d323, 0x0010c, 0x3bfbb

#endif
};
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your ultimate goal? Is it to understand the CABAC context tables or just printing out rates while encoding ?